# Какие ошибки в коде страницы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте, я в веб-разработке всего дней десять от силы, назвать меня начинающим можно с натяжкой. Пожалуйста, посмотрите код моего сайта на ошибки, чтобы я мог знать, в каком направлении мне следует подтягивать свои знания)
Сайт: [shveypokrov.ru](http://shveypokrov.ru)

```css
/*This is CSS RESET*/
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/
/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/

body, html {
 background-color: #B63D32;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
}
div {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
#page-wrapper {
 width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
header{
 width: 96.1%;
 min-height: 202px;
 /*border*/
 border-top: 22px solid #000;
 border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 /*border ends*/
}
.container {
 max-width: 898px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
 width: 85px;
 height: 86px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 2px;
 padding-right: 9.85%;
}
.title__first {
 margin-top: 6px;
 font-size: 36px;
 font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
 text-align: center;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 17px;
 font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 1px; 
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 3px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.title__second {
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
 text-shadow: 1px 0.5px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 background-color: #666666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
 letter-spacing: -0.55px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
.main__menu {
 height: 13px;
 float: none;
 margin-top: 1.5%;
}
.main__menu ul li > a:hover {
 color: black;
 transition: 0.2s;
}
.menu {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 left: -11.1%;
}
ul {
 padding-top: 11px;
}
.menu li {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 10%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 23%;
}
.menu li a {
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 19px;
 font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
section {
 width: 96.1%;
 height: 100%;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -16px;

 /*border ends*/ 
}
.container1 {
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 16px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 background-color: #BFBFBF;
 background-image: url(../img/fon.png);
 -webkit-background-size: cover; /* Для хрома */
 -moz-background-size: cover;  /* Для лисы*/
 -o-background-size: cover;  /* Для оперы*/
 -ms-background-size: cover;  /* Для ИЭ*/
 background-size: cover;  /* Для закрипления*/
 background-position: 19%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.spisok {
 height: 100%;
 width: 238px;
 position: relative;
 top: -100%;
 background-color: #7B2019;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
 border-left: 0px solid #000;
 border-right: 15px solid #000;
 /*border ends*/ 
} 
.spisok li {
 width: 195px;
 height: 45px;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 13.2px;
 background-image: url(../img/span_menu.png);
 color: rgba(222,222,222 .1); 
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#oblacheniya {
 margin-top: 16px;
}

.spisok li a {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 0.5px;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 position: relative;
 display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 9px;
    
}
.spisok ul  > li:hover{
 background-image: url(../img/span_menu_hover.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.spisok ul li > a:hover{
 text-shadow: gold 0 0 40px; /* Свечение голубого цвета */
    color: white;

}

.spisok ul li a p {
 padding-top: 14px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

#ugol {
 background-image: url(../img/span_menu_black.png);
}


.text-div {
 width: 158px;
 height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -9px;

}
.letter-spacing {
 letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.ryasi {
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.Nashi_Tseny {
 float: none;
 margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%; /* Ширина слоя в процентах */
    height: 100%; /* Высота слоя в процентах */
    position: relative;
    top: 4%;
    left: -0.5%;
}
.text_1 {
 width: 600px;
 height: 400px;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 25px;
 font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 left: 8%;
 top: 1%;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 35px;
 font-family: Impact;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 5px;
 text-decoration: underline;
 text-align: center;
}
strong {
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 16px;
}
#vocem_tis {
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: 900;
 font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
}

footer {
 width: 96.1%;
 height: 115px;
 /*border*/
 border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
 border-left: 22px solid #000;
 border-right: 22px solid #000;
 margin: 0 auto;
 /*border ends*/
}
```

```html
<?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
?>
<section>
 <div class="container1">
  <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
   <div>
     <h2>Наши цены:</h2> <br><br><br><br>
   </div>
   <div class="text_1">
    <p>Облачения:<p>
    -иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span id="vocem_tis">9000</span></strong> рублей с шикарными галунами <br>
    -иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span id="vocem_tis">10000</strong></span> рублей<strong>*</strong><br> 
    Подрясники:<br>
    Подризники:<br>
    Рясы:<br>
    Стихари:<br>
    Скуфии:от 800 рублей;<br>
    Камилавки:от 1700<br>
    Крещальные:<br>
    Облачения для храма:<br>
    Вышитые кресты:<br>
    Кадильный уголь:<br>

    *парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу
   </div>
  </div>
  <?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/left_menu.php';
        ?>
 </div>
</section>
<?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: Для первого раза сойдет.

Comment: @websnap пожалуйста, укажите на ошибки, если у Вас есть время)

Comment: Их слишком много, всех не перечесть :) Но это нормально, все с чего-то начинали. Моя первая верстка была не лучше.
Например не используйте id для стилизации. Они используются для java script, да и там вполне можно без них обойтись.
Ненужные свойства прописаны. У вас где-то float: none указан. Зачем если по умолчанию у всех элементов обтекания и  так нет?
Много где у вас высота указана. В большинстве случаев это лишнее, тем более в процентах.
Футер не прижат к низу страницы, из-за этого такое вот отображение в "Контакты".

Comment: В секции "наши цены" список, а не как у вас текст + <br>
<br><br><br><br> - это вообще ужас :) Для этого есть margin/padding
css reset - забудьте. Используйте normalize. Пока не обязательно вникать что там написано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде не менял ничего, все описал в комментариями на местах ошибок, что бы было более наглядно и понятно

```css
/*This is CSS RESET*/


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  /* зачем задавать выравнивание текста всем элементам, а потом где-то менять */
  line-height: 1;
  /*убрать наследуется всеми элементами*/
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  /*что за content none задаешь пустой и тут же none какой смысл?*/
  content: none;
  /*убрать*/
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/


/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/


/*This is the END of CSS RESET*/

body,
html {
  background-color: #B63D32;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*ненужное  auto, убрать выше уже прописано правило зачем писать одно и тоже */
  padding: 0;
  /* убрать выше уже прописано правило зачем писать одно и тоже  */
  position: relative;
  /* убрать*/
  /*
   добавить 
   если body не задать высоту, то его по сути у body нет
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   */
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  /*убрать так как уже задано в html и body */
  padding: 0;
  /*убрать так как уже задано в html и body */
}

header {
  width: 96.1%;
  min-height: 202px;
  /*border*/
  border-top: 22px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
  border-left: 22px solid #000;
  border-right: 22px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border ends*/
}

.container {
  max-width: 898px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 85px;
  height: 86px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-right: 9.85%;
}

.title__first {
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.title__second {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 0.5px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background-color: #666666;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  letter-spacing: -0.55px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.main__menu {
  height: 13px;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
}

.main__menu ul li>a:hover {
  color: black;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -11.1%;
}

ul {
  padding-top: 11px;
}

.menu li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 23%;
}

.menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

section {
  width: 96.1%;
  height: 100%;
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 13px solid #000;
  border-left: 22px solid #000;
  border-right: 22px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: -16px;
  /*border ends*/
}

.container1 {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
  background-image: url(../img/fon.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  /* Для хрома */
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  /* Для лисы*/
  -o-background-size: cover;
  /* Для оперы*/
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  /* Для ИЭ*/
  background-size: cover;
  /* Для закрипления*/
  background-position: 19%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.spisok {
  height: 100%;
  width: 238px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
  background-color: #7B2019;
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
  border-left: 0px solid #000;
  border-right: 15px solid #000;
  /*border ends*/
}

.spisok li {
  width: 195px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 13.2px;
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu.png);
  color: rgba(222, 222, 222 .1);
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#oblacheniya {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.spisok li a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: CyrillicOldBold, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  display: list-item;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 9px;
}

.spisok ul>li:hover {
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu_hover.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  /*префексы уже сто лет как не нужны их можно убрать  не вспомню щас, но есть парочка правил где надо, но transition и без них работает */
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: All 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.spisok ul li>a:hover {
  text-shadow: gold 0 0 40px;
  /* Свечение голубого цвета */
  color: white;
}

.spisok ul li a p {
  padding-top: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#ugol {
  background-image: url(../img/span_menu_black.png);
}

.text-div {
  width: 158px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -9px;
}

.letter-spacing {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.ryasi {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.Nashi_Tseny {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /* Ширина слоя в процентах */
  height: 100%;
  /* Высота слоя в процентах */
  position: relative;
  top: 4%;
  left: -0.5%;
}

.text_1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  left: 8%;
  top: 1%;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Impact;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-align: center;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#vocem_tis {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

footer {
  width: 96.1%;
  height: 115px;
  /*border*/
  border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
  border-left: 22px solid #000;
  border-right: 22px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*border ends*/
}
```

```html
<?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php';
?>
<section>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="Nashi_Tseny">
      <div>
        <!--что за br убрать -->
        <h2>Наши цены:</h2> <br><br><br><br>
      </div>
      <div class="text_1">

        <!---->
        <p>Облачения:
          <p>
            <!--все строчки ниже обернуть в тег <Р> убрать все BR выравнивание стилизовать с помощью  css-->
            -иерейские <strong>шелковые</strong> от <strong><span id="vocem_tis">9000</span></strong> рублей с шикарными галунами <br> -иерейские <strong>парчевые</strong> от <strong><span id="vocem_tis">10000</strong></span> рублей<strong>*</strong><br>            Подрясники:
            <br> Подризники:
            <br> Рясы:
            <br> Стихари:
            <br> Скуфии:от 800 рублей;<br> Камилавки:от 1700<br> Крещальные:
            <br> Облачения для храма:<br> Вышитые кресты:<br> Кадильный уголь:<br> *парчевые облачения с индийскими галунами шьются по заказу
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/left_menu.php';
        ?>
  </div>
</section>
<?php  
 require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/objects/footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте.

1. Вот отличный сервис, чтобы проверить ошибки: https://www.w3.org/ (у Вас их 25)
2. У вас пустое место внизу, думаю такого не должно быть [image: Футер]
3. Очень странная структура html кода. Все можно было сделать намного проще, посмотрите уроки верстки, там все подробно рассказывается.
4. У вас стили находятся в html файле. Это очень плохой тон, по хорошему стили в в одном файле, скрипты в другом.
5. `<div id="page-wrapper">` нет закрывающего тега `</div>`

Comment: Вы проверяли в CSS Validator? Проверил в нём, 1 ошибка, 9 предупреждений. Можно, пожалуйста, прямую ссылку на тот валидатор, где Вы проверяли?

Comment: @Quick Brown Fox   я проверял html, а не css  https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/bD1g/cfYcgaVZB  вот скрин ошибок